# how to pass parameter in a function which is a value of dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i have two dictionary

```py
dict1 = {
    "abc": sm.xyz.cdd(),
    "def": sm.acf.fdr(),
    "ghi": sm.rty.qsd(),
}
```

I need to create a function that takes 2 parameters 1st is the key of dict1 and 2nd parameter would be a string and i want the output

```py
fun("abc", "log")

# then this must be my output
sm.xyz.cdd("log")
```

Comment: This is one dictionary... Your dict1 should be `dict1={"abc":sm.xyz.cdd, ...}` (no parenthesis), otherwise you already calling a function. As for the function, what have you tried so far to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in a comment, you can remove the parentheses when defining the dictionary to store the functions as a value associated with a key. Then you can write a simple function that accesses the function in the dictionary and returns the output with the given input:

```py
def fun(dictKey, funInput):
    
    return dict1[dictKey](funInput)
```

And then you can just call the function with `fun("abc","log")`.

Comment: This is the simple, minimalistic, and "correct" answer

Answer (score 0):

```py
dict1={
  "abc":sm.xyz.cdd,
  "def":sm.acf.fdr,
  "ghi":sm.rty.qsd,
}
def fun(key, *args, **vaargs):
    dict1[key](*args, **vaargs)
```

Comment: You forgot the `return`. And `**vaargs` are keyword arguments while OP passes arguments as positional arguments (`*args`). To be more general you should have both 
 - `(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot it, fixed it now, thanks

Comment: in this my string that i am passing is args or vaargs?

Comment: @priston it is going to be in `args` list

Comment: i didn't understand how to call it how will i call fun("abc","log")

Comment: When you now call `fun("abc", "log")`, `args` will be `("log", )` and `vaargs` will be an empty dict. With the * and ** operators the tuple and dictionary gets unpact for the function call.